# How do I join results of looping script into a single variable?

Tags: python, arrays, debugging, loops, python-2.7

I have looping script returning different filtered results, I can make this data return as an array for each of the different filter classes. However I am unsure of the best method to join all of these arrays together.

```
import mechanize
import urllib
import json
import re
import random
import datetime
from sched import scheduler
from time import time, sleep
from sets import Set

##### Code to loop the script and set up scheduling time
s = scheduler(time, sleep)
random.seed()

##### Code to stop duplicates part 1 
userset = set ()

def run_periodically(start, end, interval, func):
    event_time = start
    while event_time < end:
        s.enterabs(event_time, 0, func, ())
        event_time += interval + random.randrange(-5, 10)
    s.run()

##### Code to get the data required from the URL desired
def getData():  
    post_url = "URL OF INTEREST"
    browser = mechanize.Browser()
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

##### These are the parameters you've got from checking with the aforementioned tools
    parameters = {'page' : '1',
                  'rp' : '250',
                  'sortname' : 'race_time',
                  'sortorder' : 'asc'
                 }
##### Encode the parameters
    data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
    trans_array = browser.open(post_url,data).read().decode('UTF-8')

    xmlload1 = json.loads(trans_array)
    pattern2 = re.compile('/control/profile/view/(.*)\' title=')
    pattern4 = re.compile('title=\'posted: (.*) strikes:')
    pattern5 = re.compile('strikes: (.*)\'><img src=')

    for row in xmlload1['rows']:
        cell = row["cell"]

##### defining the Keys (key is the area from which data is pulled in the XML) for use in the pattern finding/regex

        user_delimiter = cell['username']
        selection_delimiter = cell['race_horse']

        user_numberofselections = float(re.findall(pattern4, user_delimiter)[0])
        user_numberofstrikes = float(re.findall(pattern5, user_delimiter)[0])
        strikeratecalc1 = user_numberofstrikes/user_numberofselections
        strikeratecalc2 = strikeratecalc1*100
        userid_delimiter_results = (re.findall(pattern2, user_delimiter)[0])


##### Code to stop duplicates throughout the day part 2 (skips if the id is already in the userset)

        if userid_delimiter_results in userset: continue;
        userset.add(userid_delimiter_results)

        arraym = ""
        arrayna = ""

        if strikeratecalc2 > 50 and strikeratecalc2 < 100):

            arraym0 = "System M" 
            arraym1 = "user id = ",userid_delimiter_results
            arraym2 = "percantage = ",strikeratecalc2,"%"
            arraym3 = ""
            arraym = [arraym0, arraym1, arraym2, arraym3]

        if strikeratecalc2 > 0 and strikeratecalc2 < 50):

            arrayna0 = "System NA" 
            arrayna1 = "user id = ",userid_delimiter_results
            arrayna2 = "percantage = ",strikeratecalc2,"%"
            arrayna3 = ""
            arrayna = [arrayna0, arrayna1, arrayna2, arrayna3]


getData()

run_periodically(time()+5, time()+1000000, 10, getData)
```

What I want to be able to do, is return both the 'arraym' and the 'arrayna' as one final Array, however due to the looping nature of the script upon each loop of the script the old 'arraym'/'arrayna' are overwritten, currently my attempts to yield one array containing all of the data has resulted in the last userid for 'systemm' and the last userid for 'sustemna'. This is obviously because, upon each run of the loop it overwrites the old 'arraym' and the 'arrayna' however I do not know of a way to get around this, so that all of my data can be accumulated in one array. Please note, I have been coding for cumulatively two weeks now, so there may well be some simple function to overcome this problem.

Kind regards AEA

Comment: It's usually helpful if you can summarize your question/code into a much smaller example of your issue.  With all this code, it makes answering your question difficult.

Comment: I did try to summarise the code as much as I could, essentially it is just those two arrays at the bottom that I need to join into one array,  but I thought I should make it obvious that this code is looping (didn't want to leave out some code that is important when considering the answer) Kind regards AEA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking at that huge code segment, typically you can do something like:

```
my_array = [] # Create an empty list
for <some loop>:
    my_array.append(some_value)


# At this point, my_array is a list containing some_value for each loop iteration
print(my_array)
```

Look into python's [list.append()](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

So your code might look something like:

```
#...
arraym = []
arrayna = []

for row in xmlload1['rows']:
    #...
    if strikeratecalc2 > 50 and strikeratecalc2 < 100):
        arraym.append("System M")
        arraym.append("user id = %s" % userid_delimiter_results)
        arraym.append("percantage = %s%%" % strikeratecalc2)
        arraym.append("")
    if strikeratecalc2 > 0 and strikeratecalc2 < 50):
        arrayna.append("System NA")
        arrayna.append("user id = %s" % userid_delimiter_results)
        arrayna.append("percantage = %s%%" % strikeratecalc2)
        arrayna.append("")
#...
```